how to configure spring boot kerberos implementation to get windows users id stored in ticket cache to achieve sso
im new to spring boot, im trying to integrate spring boot security with kerberos so that i can achieve sso and get windows user info in my application.  since my windows user credential is stored in memory (i believe i dont need to setup krb5.conf and jaas.conf), all i've done so far is updated my pom.xml and securityconfiguration.java:
pom.xml:
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Boot Starter Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security Kerberos -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.kerberos</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-kerberos-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.kerberos</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-kerberos-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Thymeleaf for HTML templates -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

securityconfiguration.java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.client.sun.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.web.authentication.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.web.authentication.SpnegoEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandling ->
                exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint(spnegoEntryPoint())
            )
            .addFilterBefore(spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SpnegoEntryPoint spnegoEntryPoint() {
        return new SpnegoEntryPoint();
    }

    @Bean
    public SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
        SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        List<org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider> providers = new ArrayList<>();
        providers.add(kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider());
        return new ProviderManager(providers);
    }

    @Bean
    public KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider() {
        KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider provider = new KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setTicketValidator(sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator() {
        SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator ticketValidator = new SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator();
        // Do not set a service provider to leverage the Windows ticket cache
        // Do not set a keytab location to leverage the Windows ticket cache
        ticketValidator.setDebug(true);
        return ticketValidator;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> {
            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            return new User(username, "", authorities);
        };
    }
}


however, when i try to start my application, its still said that both service pricipal and key tab must be specified.  the debug log is showing useTicketCache=false, but i clearly set it as true in my jaas.conf and added it to my run configuration in eclipse:
jaas.conf:
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useTicketCache=true
    doNotPrompt=true
    renewTGT=true;
};

setting jaas.conf path:
String jaasConfigPath = "C:\\path\\to\\your\\jaas.conf";
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", jaasConfigPath);

please let me know if im missing anything, or how to tell the application that im trying to get user info from memory cache, im using windows 10, java 21, spring boot 3.3.2 and eclipse.  thanks for the help

Are you trying to set up a Kerberos client that sends user credentials somewhere, or are you trying to set up a service that receives them? You are mixing up parameters of both configurations.

hi, im trying to receive user info only.

This is an HTTP webapp, right? Are you trying to get user info of the visiting user, or are you trying to get info of the user who's started the app?

yes, this is a webapp, im trying to get visiting user info, the user trying to access the webapp, without needing him/her to login since they have already logged in to windows domain.  i dont have a key tab location, since when i use klist, i see 4 or 5 entries, none of them have key cache location specified, im assuming it is stored in memory.

You have some things completely backwards.

i dont have a key tab location, since when i use klist, i see 4 or 5 entries, none of them have key cache location specified, im assuming it is stored in memory

Well yes, but they're in the client's memory, and your webapp's Java code is not running on the client system, thus it cannot see the client's memory or the client's ticket cache. So it makes no sense to find a server-side location from a client-side command.
(This is still true even if the webapp happens to run on 'localhost' at the moment – the Java code and the browser still remain separate entities that only talk through HTTP, and the webapp cannot automatically see the client's cached tickets regardless. Of course, once it is deployed, it will be on a different machine altogether.)
Second, what you see in klist is not a keytab. Don't confuse a ticket cache with a keytab – in a way they're completely opposite things; in general the ticket cache holds the user's login credentials, while the keytab holds the server's credentials. The keytab is kinda like a SSL certificate.
(Of course, there are exceptions – sometimes services act as clients and have a ticket cache, and sometimes clients have keytabs, but hopefully that doesn't confuse the point too much.)

however, when i try to start my application, its still said that both service pricipal and key tab must be specified. the debug log is showing useTicketCache=false, but i clearly set it as true in my jaas.conf and added it to my run configuration in eclipse: jaas.conf:

useTicketCache is irrelevant, because a Kerberos service does not have a ticket cache (or a TGT for that matter) – only the client has those things.
(This setting only exists for situations where the Java webapp itself was acting as a client to some other Kerberos-based system (e.g. talking to an API or LDAP). You might need it later on, but not for this particular task.)
Again, do not confuse a ticket cache with a keytab. The server does not have a ticket cache, but it requires a keytab – you must get one issued, and you must specify one in the server's config. The browser running on the client would be the one accessing its ticket cache and sending a ticket over the network to your webapp, and the webapp would verify it against its keytab.

many thanks for this detailed explanation, now many things made sense.  i am running the web app on my localhost, no idea i cant test it that way.  still got a few questions:  does that mean i can only test this setup by deploying it on a different pc also in the domain?  im using chrome, do i need to do anything special in the browsers enable kerberos authentication, or it's automatic?

If the webapp gets its service credentials from a keytab file (as opposed to letting Windows SSPI take care of it), then its server doesn't actually need to be "in the domain" as the keytab's contents provide the needed relationship instead. So you can indeed run the app on localhost for testing. But you must access it via the correct domain name that matches the service principal – e.g. if you got a keytab for HTTP/app.example.com then you must access it via http(s)://app.example.com, even if you have to edit the hosts file to make that work.

As for browsers, it varies. I believe both Chrome and Edge follow the global Windows (well, MS IE) "zone" settings – if the site belongs to the Intranet or Trusted zone then it allows "Integrated Windows Authentication", otherwise no. Whereas Firefox instead has an about:config setting – you have to set network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris to either .example.com for a single domain, or a more broad https:// (literally that) for all HTTPS websites, or similar.

To clarify the first point: Windows has an OS-wide Kerberos implementation, where both user tickets and service keys are managed by the OS as part of the domain join – when a service is set to run under a "service account", its Kerberos keys come from that account. But Java also has its own, completely independent, Kerberos implementation that does not rely on Windows accounts in any way – instead it lets you provide the same service account's key directly as a keytab file and it verifies tickets without going through Windows. (I thought Java could work both ways, but apparently not.)

thanks a lots, the info provided definitely pointed me in the right direction
